# run a VR enabled Unity executable from a remote computer with psexec

Tags: unity-game-engine, psexec, virtual-reality, oculus, remote-execution

I am using PSTools to run a **VR enabled Unity executable from a remote computer**. The command looks for the executable directly on the target PC's file system (psexec \remotecomputer -i -s "c:/Users/me/Desktop/Build/TestMall.exe"), where the .exe and the _Data files are stored. It's not copied over the network.

The executable launches ok, except that **the VR capabilities are ignored** (no tracking and nothing displayed in Oculus Rift). Now, if I run the same .exe directly from the target PC, it works perfectly fine in Rift.

Maybe there are some special arguments that I should consider, when I send the running command remotely?

Anyone had a similar problem? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the architecture type on build window.